# How to create Spell Indicator Combat

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm trying to do a League of Legends style combat. I have some ways that I have thought about doing it. I could use a range of vector 3's and say that if the enemy is in between those then the ability would hit. I could also use a collider that is a child to the player.

Both of these ways seem okay but I'm sure there is a more effective way.

This asset pack actually seems quite on point to what I'm attempting if anyone needs reference.

https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/particles-effects/status-indicators-88156

Comment: They're called "decals"

Comment: I've been trying to find a name, Ill research into decals.